# Set values for form field by query using filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to set the item in dropdown using the query in the form. I want to add employee and the select company which using filter Is_Del= 0. I do not know how to set values for the drop down and where to write this query.

I tried to put in Forms.py, but it is not working.

This is form.py

```
class EmployeeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('Emp_Name','Emp_company','Emp_Dept','Emp_Join_Date', 'Emp_End_Date')

        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(EmployeeCreateForm, self).clean()
            Emp_Name = cleaned_data.get('Emp_Name')
            Emp_company = cleaned_data.get('Emp_company')
            Emp_Dept = cleaned_data.get('Emp_Dept')
            Emp_Join_Date = cleaned_data.get('Emp_Join_Date')
            Emp_End_Date = cleaned_data.get('Emp_End_Date')
            return cleaned_data

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeCreateForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Emp_company'].queryset = Company.objects.filter(Is_Del=0)
```

and below is my view.py

```
class EmployeeCraeteView(LoginRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    model=Employee
    form = EmployeeCreateForm
    success_message = " Employee Craeted successfully!"
    success_url="../../company/all-companies"
    template_name = 'employee_form.html'
    fields =[
            'Emp_Name','Emp_company','Emp_Dept','Emp_Join_Date',
            'Emp_End_Date'
            ]
    companies= Company.objects.filter(Is_Del=0)

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.Emp_Crt_By = self.request.user
        if form.cleaned_data['Emp_Join_Date'] >= form.cleaned_data['Emp_End_Date']:
            form.add_error('Emp_End_Date', 'Joining date should be less than Ending date')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        return super(EmployeeCraeteView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I want to show only this companies in the form which are filtered by Is_Del =0

Comment: What is not working exactly? Please be specific and tell what you see or what error is raised. Just 'it's not working' isn't good enough.

Comment: No error is showing but shows all companies instead of just filtered one. It means the filter query is not working.

Comment: Is `Emp_company` a `ForeignKey` field in the `Employee` model? And why do you have `.values('id')` in your queryset, you want to display a list of ids to the user (rather than the company name)?

Comment: yes you are correct `Emp_Company` is foreign Key and I want to display company name. Pardon me I'm new to Django so do I need to remove `.values('id')`? DO you mean I should use `Company.objects.filter(Is_Del=0)`  ? i do not know where and how should i write this?

Comment: You're doing it correctly (except for `values('id')`, that's why I was asking what you were seeing.

Comment: This lead me to conclude your form wasn't instantiated at all (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EmployeeCreateView` is wrong:

- Remove the attributes `form`, `fields` and `companies`
- Add `form_class = EmployeeCreateForm`.

The reason is that `form` doesn't do anything in a `CreateView` (see [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/)). To use a custom form class, you need to pass it to `form_class`.

Your `CreateView` was dynamically creating the form using a `modelform_factory` with the `fields` you defined (if you hadn't added those you'd have seen your mistake immediately) and so your `EmployeeCreateForm` is never instantiated.

Comment: Note: you can remove the `clean(self)` method entirely from your `EmployeeCreateForm` since it doesn't do anything at all. The super() classes' methods will be called anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it works perfectly fine without `clean(self)`